# Performing math on JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

Is there a way to overwrite the behavior of math operators like `+-*/` in JavaScript?

Lets say for example I have a person object:

```
var Person = (function() {
  function _Person(age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
  /* I was hoping something like this would work
  _Person.prototype.add = function(input) {
    return this.age + input.age;
  };*/
  return _Person;
})();
```

and I make two people and want to add them together to get their total age:

```
var p1 = new Person(24);
var p2 = new Person(25);
var totalAge = p1+p2;//should equal 49
```

I've like to be able to implement a prototype method or something to specify what to do when two objects are added together. Other languages have this, for example python has `__add__`, does javascript have a way of doing this?

Here is the sample code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HYrPM/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript has no operator overload feature.

Comment: Ah operator overload, that was the term I was missing from my google searches. Thanks, and bummer :)

Comment: you don't need to overload anything.  see my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload the ops, but you can add a `valueOf` function to person which can return whatever you want (I know this was asked 6 months ago, but someone just edited it :))

```
function Person( age ){
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.valueOf = function(){
    return this.age;
}

var p1 = new Person( 24 )
  , p2 = new Person( 25 );

p1+p2 // 49
```